# Electric Power of Displacement Current

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, power

Say we have displacement current $I_d$ inside a plate capacitor of alternating voltage $V(t)$.

We use the formula for electric power on the displacement current:

$P=I_dV$

What does $P$ account for? Does it have any meaning? Is it related to the power of the magnetic field inside and around the capacitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this power $P=I_dV$ has a meaning.
It is the change per time of the electric field energy
stored in the capacitor.

To see how this comes about, let us begin with the
[electric energy density](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html) (i.e. energy per volume). It is
$$\eta_e=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2$$
where $E$ is the electric field strength.

The electric field within the capacitor is nearly homogenous.
So the total energy in the volume between the plates is
$$\mathcal{E}=\eta_e A d=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2Ad$$
where $A$ is the plate area, and $d$ is the distance
between the plates.

Now let us calculate the time derivative of this energy $\mathcal{E}$:
$$\begin{align}
\dot{\mathcal{E}}&=\epsilon_0 E\dot{E}Ad \\
&=\underbrace{\epsilon_0\dot{E}A}_{=I_d}\ \underbrace{Ed}_{=V} \\
&=I_d V
\end{align}$$
Here we recognized the displacement current $I_d$
and the voltage $V$ between the plates,
and finally arrived at the power $I_dV$.